# SFDX Unlocked Dependencies for managed packages

Tags: salesforcedx

I have created a Package consider it as 'package A'  and added managed packages dependencies in sfdx-project.json and i was able to create a version of it and install it successfully in the sandbox. But when i create another package (package b)  in same project which has dependency on 'package A' and it is giving me the following error when trying to create version of it.

> An error occurred while trying to install a package dependency, ID 04t....: The package you're installing depends on package 'INsight', version '1.971                                134'. Install package 'INsight' in the target org before you install package 'package A'.

But 'INsight' is a managed package and is already in devhub org.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer or solution to this? I'm having the same issue.